# How to add index on extract() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a query with following `WHERE` condition in postgres database:

`WHERE extract(EPOCH FROM created_at) BETWEEN 1511132400 AND 1511737199`

How can I add the index so query with this condition uses it? Creating index on `created_at` does not help and the index is not used.

Currently the `EXPLAIN` on a query like that gives:

`Filter: (date_part('epoch'::text, created_at) >= '1511132400'::double precision) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, created_at) <= '1511737199'::double precision)`

(The `extract()` statement is generated by Grafana so that's the reason I'm (or Grafana is) using it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [function based index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_epoch_idx ON my_table (extract(EPOCH FROM created_at));
```

Comment: Glad to help you @simPod

Comment: @simPod Or, yet another solution. Instead of modifying the column modify the constant(s). Smth like `created_at BETWEEN to_timestamp(1511132400) AND to_timestamp(1511737199)`. It allows to use existing index, not creating another one.

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you. I have expressed incorrectly what Grafana generates. Grafana builds the whole statement I described after `WHERE`, not just `extract()` So I cannot modify timestamps without modifying Grafana. But thanks for help!